# How to get back to project after adding a header file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have added a header file for a project I am working on and I can't figure out how to get out of the header file and back to where I code. Am I just being stupid?

Comment: check under menu point Window or press Alt-W. Normally the files would be in tabs though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it easy, you only need to copy the header file you want to add to the project file and you can use `#include" "`to call the header file. In my example, I copied the Header.h file to the project file, and then Use `#include"Header.h"` in the .cpp file, which can use the content in the header file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I do not write the project I am working on from where I created the header file, and instead create an entirely new project and add the header file to the local directory there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).